# Is it hard to find a big random easy to factor number?

Tags: prime-numbers, complexity

Suppose that I give you the challenge of successfully factoring **any** very big random number. That is, you pick a big random number (say, 65536 bits) and try to factor it. If you manage to, you win. If you don't, you can keep trying, or pick another random number, until you factor any big number. How hard is to win this challenge?

To put it in another way, suppose that I offer you a lot of money if you give me a tuple `(nonce, rnd, factors)`, where `nonce` is any number selected by you, `rnd` is the 65536-bit variable length SHA3 output of the nonce, and `factors` is the list of prime factors of `rnd`. Will you be able to take my money?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this is feasible. Just generate sufficiently many nonce, rnd values, and you will eventually stumble upon a prime (or a number that can be factored into a large prime and a number of small prime factors). This is how most probabilistic prime generators operate.

Comment: Ah, makes sense. The probability that a number is prime is roughly `1/ln(n)`, so it isn't that unlikely that a big random number is prime, and primality checks are fast. So, after a few attempts we find a prime one and immediately answer the challenge. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Just to be a little bit more precise, finding a random 64-bit prime number takes roughly 44 attempts, and it scales linearly, so finding a random 128-bit prime number takes roughly 88 attempts and so on. So, to be precise, the stated problem has at least a `O(N)` solution, where `N` is the hash size in bits and is, thus, very easy (not considering the complexity of the primality check though).